# All linear maps $T:V \to W$ is a vector space Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

[Definition of the linear map w.r.t addition and multiplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqRbI.jpg)

[Proving closure in scalar multiplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrmln.jpg)

I was advised to prove closure in scalar multiplication by proving $\lambda \Phi$ to be linear.

If I want to prove the multiplicative identity exist can I just fix $\lambda = 1$ then

$\forall \vec{v} \in V$ we have

$(1*\Phi)(\vec{v}) = 1*\Phi(\vec{v})$ (From the definition of scalar multiplication)

$\iff  \Phi(\vec{v})$

Comment: It's looking good so far. I have a small note though: use $=$ instead of $\iff$, because the two vector quantities are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you want to prove that the sum of any two linear maps $\Phi \text { and } \Psi $ is linear,  and that $\lambda \Phi $ is linear for any scalar $\lambda $.   To prove the latter, $\lambda \Phi (\vec v +\vec w)=\lambda (\Phi \vec v +\Phi \vec w)=\lambda \Phi \vec v +\lambda \Phi \vec w $ and for, any scalar  $\beta $, $\lambda \Phi \beta \vec v=\lambda \beta \Phi \vec v=\beta \lambda \Phi \vec v $. 
Then you have 8 properties to check. ..